# Почему QTableWidgetItem некорректно отображается?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, настройки, qtablewidgetitem

В программе использую QTableWidget, столкнулся с багом, который не исправляется изменением размеров шрифта, размером ячеек и самой таблицы. Но заметил особенность, что в системах с параметрами дисплея "масштаб и разметка 100%" все отображается корректно:
[image: Масштаб и разметка 100%]

[image: корректное отображение таблицы]

Но в системах где настройки дисплея "масштаб и разметка" отличаются от 100%, часть таблицы скрывается и никакие изменения ее размеров не позволяют корректно отобразить содержимое.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как с этим бороться, чтобы таблица во всех случаях отображалась корректно?

Comment: поставьте для начала стиль Fusion, "системные" не очень хорошо себя ведут иногда

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.